# Installing Data table as offline to my html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatables

Why my data table is not functioning even though i already have all the data table libraries (offline)?! please help me

I want to use the data table but it's not working

Comment: Could you please show your code or give us more debugging details?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] to help the community to recreate your problem. We have no idea what your code looks like. All we can do (right now) is guess. If you are using locally installed ("offline") libraries, your question needs to show us where those are and how you are referring to them. You also need to show us any browser console errors you may be getting. Open the console using F12.

Comment: You can also read [ask] and browse the links it contains for more help and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation says you need these files:

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

then code for the table:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

html table:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011-04-25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

Comment: The question refers to "offline" libraries.

Comment: @andrewJames I know! but you can save the files content as offline files! Solution: open the link, right click and save as offline file, which you can link in your html head